# nvidia-410 not able to install

Tags: nvidia

I just try to install `nvidia-410` but after I added the ppa with

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
and then `apt-update` it just doesn't find the driver. I tried to remove the files from the sources.list.d/ directory and add them into the base sources.list but that doesn't work, too.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: I have ubuntu Version 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Install it by this command

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-410
```

They changed metapackage names in this PPA.